# Delphi 6 : breakpoint triggered on non-VCL thread stops main thread repaints

Tags: multithreading, delphi, vcl, repaint, wndproc

I have a multi-threaded Delphi 6 Pro application that I am currently working on heavily.  If I set a breakpoint on any code that runs in the context of the Main thread (VCL thread) I don't have any problems.  However, if a breakpoint is triggered on any code in one of my other threads, after I continue the application from the breakpoint, all repaints to the VCL components on the main thread (including the main form) don't happen anymore.  The application isn't dead because other background code keeps running, just the main thread.  It's as if the windows message dispatcher has been corrupted or rendered dormant.

Note, in this application I allocate my own WndProc() via allocateHwnd() on the main form because I need to catch certain registered messages.  From that WndProc() I dispatch any custom messages I handle and if the current message is not handled by my code, I pass the message on by calling the main form's inherited WndProc().  If I do handle the current message I simply return from my WndProc() with Msg.Result set to 1 to tell the dispatcher that the message was handled.  I can't simply override the TForm WndProc() instead of allocating my own WndProc() because for some reason the Delphi VCL does not pass through registered messages instantiated with the Windows API RegisterWindowMessage() call.

Has anybody experienced this in similar context and if so, what did you do to fix it?

-- roscherl

Comment: I have never experienced problems with processing Windows messages in overridden WndProc. Maybe a code sample will help to see what is wrong.

Comment: My only thought is to check that the window is actually not refreshing by covering it and uncovering it. It could be the window doesn't know it needs to update.

Comment: it's not a fix, but what happens when you force an update/paint/refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you call `AllocateHWnd`, that means you've created *another window*. You mustn't just take the messages that were addressed to that window and forward them to your form's window. Doing that, you're bound to screw things up in your program, although I'm not sure exactly how. Painting problems sound plausible. You should make sure it's really just painting problems and not that your main thread is still suspended. The debugger should be able to tell you that. (You should call `DefWindowProc` to make your allocated window handle messages you're not prepared to handle yourself. And returning 1 doesn't tell the dispatcher anything; the dispatcher doesn't care — whoever called `SendMessage` wants to know the result.)

I promise you that forms are completely capable of receiving registered window messages. Override `WndProc` or assign a new value to the `WindowProc` property (and remember to save the old value so you can call it after handling your own messages). The source of your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Rob, those are good points you make.  Regarding registered messages, I ran the same test twice where I reverted back to sub-classing the form's WndProc().  The registered messages never showed up, but they always do via the WndProc() I set up with allocateHwnd().  I don't know what else to say or try.

Comment: Perhaps you stored the form's Handle property, and the form re-created its window in the meantime. Then you'd be left holding a stale window handle, so you'd be sending or posting your registered messages into the void.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I'm not saying the way I got past the problem is a good solution.  I need to take Rob Kennedy's notes and do some refactoring.  However, to get past the problem for now I gave the thread it's own Window and WndProc() and at the top of the thread Execute loop I have a PeekMessage() while loop with calls to TranslateMessage() and DispatchMessage().  I no longer have a problem with setting breakpoints in the thread, but obviously this compounding of WndProc() methods indicates a structural problem in my code.  I wanted to add this reply to fill out the discussion.  I'm hoping that once I put Rob's suggestions to work when I clean up my WndProc() methods on the relevant forms, especially the main form, I can get rid of the this new WndProc() that I just added to the thread.

Robert.