# Thread-safe in delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, delphi-2010

I have to modify and change some visual components in a thread and as you know it's not safe to doing this.

My question is **how to write a completely thread-safe code?** It is possible? if it is then can you please give me a simple example?

my code that is not threadsafe:

```
type
  tMyWorkerThread = class(TThread)
      public
         procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure tMyWorkerThread.Execute;
begin
  //codes
  //working with visual components
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TMyWorkerThread.Create(false);
end;
```

Thank you.

Comment: have a look at [Synchronize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize)

Comment: Use the `File->New->Other` menu, choose `Delphi Projects->Delphi Files->Thread Object`, and read the *huge comment* at the top of the new unit it creates.

Comment: *I have to modify and change some virtual component* 

Virtual component or visual component ?
And what kind of update ? progress bar may easily be done from main thread while worker trreads would only report their work - that is done in few lines of code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a VCL component from CreateAnonymousThread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739595/update-a-vcl-component-from-createanonymousthread)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My problem solved with `Synchronize!`

```
type
  tMyWorkerThread = class(TThread)
      public
         procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure tMyWorkerThread.Execute;
begin

  //codes that takes long time
  Synchronize(procedure begin
     //working with visual components
  end
  );

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TMyWorkerThread.Create(false);
end;
```

Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: Sad that you would add and accept your own answer rather than one of the other answers which are telling you the same thing. Really breaks the flow of how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 10):

Writing a thread safe code in Delphi involves the basic care you would have in any other language, which means to deal with **race conditions**. A race condition happens when different threads access the **same data**. A good way to deal with that is to declare an instance of **TCriticalSection** and wrap the *dangerous* code in it.

The code below shows a getter and a setter of a property that, by hypotesis, has a race condition.

```
constructor TMyThread.Create;
begin
  CriticalX := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy; override;
begin
  FreeAndNil(CriticalX);
end;

function TMyThread.GetX: string;
begin
  CriticalX.Enter;
  try
    Result := FX;
  finally
    CriticalX.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyThread.SetX(const value: string);
begin
  CriticalX.Enter;
  try
    FX := Value;
  finally
    CriticalX.Leave;
  end;
end;
```

Notice the use of a single instance of **TCriticalSection** (**CriticalX**) to serialize the access to the data member **FX**.

However, with Delphi you have an aditional consideration! VCL is not thread safe, so in order to avoid VCL race conditions, any operation that results in **screen changing** must run in the main thread. You get that by calling such a code inside a **Synchronize** method. Considering the class above, you should do something like this:

```
procedure TMyThread.ShowX;
begin
  Synchronize(SyncShowX);
end;

procedure TMyThread.SyncShowX;
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(FX));
end;
```

If you have **Delphi 2010** or later, there is an easier way that makes use of anonymous methods:

```
procedure TMyThread.ShowX;
begin
  Synchronize(procedure begin
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(FX));
  end);
end;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please stop calling **critical section** s - and even **event** s in an other post - **Mutex**? It could be a source of confusion if you know what a Mutex is, and can not help understand your code if you don't.

Answer (score 5):

You should only access VCL objects from main VCL thread.

Some reading methods (property getters) do work from other threads in practice - but you have to prove it in advance reading VCL sources for the specific Delphi build. Or not use it.

PS: Synchronize method runs given procedure in main VCL thread, pausing the caller thread, which may lead to a deadlock, if main thread was also blocked.

Read more: (actually making this answer to list some links)

- http://www.michael-puff.de/Programmierung/Delphi/Code-Snippets/VCLThreadDemo.shtml
- http://www.drbob42.com/uk-bug/hood-04.htm
- http://delphi.about.com/od/kbthread/a/thread-gui.htm
- [Is it better to use TThread's "Synchronize" or use Window Messages for IPC between main and child thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806339/)
- [Delphi 6 : breakpoint triggered on non-VCL thread stops main thread repaints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331622/)
- http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/win32_mthreadusemainthread_xml.html
- [Simplifying VCL thread wrapper code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780581/)
- [Update a VCL component from CreateAnonymousThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739595/)
- http://thaddy.co.uk/threads/ - the mirror of "Multithreading - The Delphi Way" by Martin Harvey
- http://otl.17slon.com/ - new Delphi approach to threading

Comment: Good list! "Multithreading - The Delphi Way" by Martin Harvey should be up there as well. In my opinion at the top position :-D Unfortunately the [original](http://www.pergolesi.demon.co.uk/prog/threads/ToC.html) is no longer around but there are several "cached" copies around: [Thaddy's](http://thaddy.co.uk/threads/) and [http://web.archive.org/](http://web.archive.org/web/20060305174604/http://www.pergolesi.demon.co.uk/prog/threads/ToC.html) are the ones I know about. It is also available through [Code Central](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/14809).

Comment: @MarjanVenema okay. Your link is rather valueable cause actually this list of mine is just 5 minutes of googling, and your links requires prior knowledge.

Comment: In case Martin's fine write-up gets lost to URL rot I have it posted on my web site:
http://www.seti.net/engineering/threads/threads.php

Comment: Well, but tdictionary is RTL.